# Designing issue for table using json

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing design issue with bootstrap and json. json is parsed with angular.
Please have a look to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/scdZMllfhsrL2eRO1pkn). You can see the result in which 
**Location, Restriction** heading's are not matched with there below data. Please help me to solve it.

My json is

```
$scope.Product = [
{
    "PolicyProductId": 7,
    "PolicyProductName": "Onview Business Mobile Deposits",
    "ProhibitedLocationDefaultAction": 10,
    "AllowedGeoLocations": [
      {
        "PolicyId": 149,
        "PolicyProductId": 7,
        "CountryId": 356,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateId": 25,
        "StateName": "Telangana",
        "City": "Hyderabad",
        "Area": 0,
        "Action": 0,
        "ActionDesc": "",
        "Status": 1
      },
      {
        "CountryId": 356,
        "StateId": 30,
        "City": "",
        "Action": 0,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "PolicyProductId": 7
      }
    ],
    "DisAllowedGeoLocations": [
      {
        "PolicyId": 149,
        "PolicyProductId": 7,
        "CountryId": 840,
        "CountryName": "UNITED STATES",
        "StateId": 0,
        "StateName": "",
        "City": "",
        "Area": 0,
        "Action": 30,
        "ActionDesc": "Send for Review",
        "Status": 0
      },
      {
        "CountryId": 356,
        "StateId": 30,
        "City": "Andaman",
        "Action": 40,
        "ActionDesc": "Don't Allow Deposit",
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "PolicyProductId": 7
      }
    ]
  },{
    "PolicyProductId": 7,
    "PolicyProductName": "Onview Deposits",
    "ProhibitedLocationDefaultAction": 10,
    "AllowedGeoLocations": [
      {
        "PolicyId": 149,
        "PolicyProductId": 7,
        "CountryId": 356,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateId": 25,
        "StateName": "Telangana",
        "City": "Hyderabad",
        "Area": 0,
        "Action": 0,
        "ActionDesc": "",
        "Status": 1
      },
      {
        "CountryId": 356,
        "StateId": 30,
        "City": "",
        "Action": 0,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "PolicyProductId": 7
      }
    ],
    "DisAllowedGeoLocations": [
      {
        "PolicyId": 149,
        "PolicyProductId": 7,
        "CountryId": 840,
        "CountryName": "UNITED STATES",
        "StateId": 0,
        "StateName": "",
        "City": "",
        "Area": 0,
        "Action": 30,
        "ActionDesc": "Send for Review",
        "Status": 0
      },
      {
        "CountryId": 356,
        "StateId": 30,
        "City": "Andaman",
        "Action": 40,
        "ActionDesc": "Don't Allow Deposit",
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "PolicyProductId": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you point out where the JSON data doesn't match?

Comment: @Aravind JSON data is correct. but when binding with html Disallowed Locations is not properly fitting.

Comment: u can try giving width to this line <td class="col-lg-6"      style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px;width:45%">{{d.City}}<span>

Comment: @aashi it doesn't work in responsive. and i am already using the bootstrap col-lg-6 which works for width

Comment: Your code looks like you only working to handle large screen devices "col-lg". To cater to others (medium, small,etc). you will need to add col-md, col-sm, etc. along with col-lg. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/